# How to create a feGaussianBlur that is rotated, ie not axis-aligned?

Tags: svg, blur

I want to use `feGaussianBlur` to blur an svg in one direction, but I would like that direction to be other than the horizontal or vertical axis.
In another rendering engine, I would assume I could do the blur first, and then rotate the graphic. However, I'm not sure how to use that using svg filters.

See below I can blur horizontally, vertically, or radially.

```css
svg{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <filter id="verticalBlur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 3" />
  </filter>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" filter="url(#verticalBlur)" />
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="horizontalBlur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3 0" />
  </filter>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" filter="url(#horizontalBlur)" />
</svg>

<svg>
  <filter id="radialBlur">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3 3" />
  </filter>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="red" filter="url(#radialBlur)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Just add a `transform="rotate(angle, cx, cy)"` to the circle. It will be applied after the filter.